# Figure out character showing as space on Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

After running an API GET request method I get a set of data whose snippet is shown by the below screenshot:

[image]

However when I run a `Merge Queries` of the `Contract` column with another table so I can get each correspondent translation to Portuguese it'll only match a few items, as shown below:

[image]

After checking the other table's contents every correspondent `Contract` was there, but then after copying the entire `Contract` column from the API dataset and pasting it to a blank Excel spreadsheet I realized that the spaces displayed on Power Query are actually some unrecognizable characters displayed as **"?" inside a diamond**:

[image]

I've already tried the `Clean` tool but it won't work. I also tried other think such as `Trim` and `Replace Values...` space by something else and no glory.

Something tells me I need to figure out which character is actually being imported instead of space so I can try to replace it on Power Query, but the question is: how can I do that? How can I turn those **"?"** into readable characters in Excel?!

Leonardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What is `�` ?

There's a special character named [`�` Replacement Char](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FFFD) which is the codepoint `u+fffd`
or in power query: `#(fffd)`

If you see one, it means text is either encoded or decoded using the wrong encoding, which causes errors.

[image]

### Check your encoding, the UI picks the wrong encoding

[image]

You say it's a web api, so **its almost always UTF-8**. However the default UI doesn't usually pick that.

- The UI often picks `1252` which is `TextEncoding.Windows`
- The web almost always uses `65001` which is `TextEncoding.Utf8`

### Wait, your query ended up with `�` ?

This is why I used the term `code-unit` instead of `code-point`. `Text.ToList` converts text into a list of 2-byte `[char]`s.

- It's just like **Dotnet** calling [String.ToCharArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=net-6.0) verses [String.EnumerateRunes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=net-6.0)
- `[char]` represents a single `utf-16 code-unit`, that is *not* the same thing as a codepoint

> How do I enumerate characters in a string?

```
= Text.ToList("hi world")
```

> How do I tell what  a character is?

```
= Character.ToNumber("x")
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/character-tonumber

### Query

```
let
    // helper function, 
    Csv = (source as list) as text =>
        Text.Combine(
            List.Transform( source, (item) =>
                try Text.From(item)
                catch (e) => "<error>"//  e[Message]
            ),
            ", "
        ),

    ReplaceSymbol = "#(fffd)",
    Source = "hi world #(0001f412)",

    Letters = Text.ToList( Source ),
    CodeUnits = List.Transform( Letters,
        (char) =>
            try Character.ToNumber( char )
            catch (e) => "invalid" meta [ Char = char ]
    ),
    CodeUnits2 = List.Transform( Letters,
        (char) =>
            try Character.ToNumber( char )
            catch (e) => ReplaceSymbol meta [ Char = char ]
    ),

    Summary = [
        Source = Source,
        CodeUnit = Csv( CodeUnits ),
        CodeUnit2 = Csv( CodeUnits2 ),
        Letters = Csv( Letters )
    ]
in
    Summary
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like:

```
=UNICODE(MID(A4, SEQUENCE(,LEN(A4)),1))
```

and fill down.  You should see codes for all the characters in the adjacent row. *(Be sure the row is clear or you will the `#SPILL!` error)*

Comment: DAX occurs after Power Query, so that would give the codepoint for `0xfffd`, (meaning you need to set the encoding before import)

Comment: @ninMonkey I agree that in order to properly import the data, he will need to set the encoding correctly. I should have emphasized that point instead of just responding to his question of *" figure out which character is actually being imported"* On the other hand, if that is the only aberrant character, he can still replace it with a `space` in PQ.